# Removing highlight in Foxit Reader after saving the document

Tags: pdf, foxitreader

I just installed Foxit Reader 2.4.1. To test the highlight function, I opened a pdf, highlighted some text, saved it, closed it and re-opened it. Now I can see the highlight, but I can't figure out how to remove the highlight after I save and re-open the document. Before closing the document, I could simply undo the operation but now I can't find a way to select the highlight. Is this not doable in Foxit Reader?

Answer (score 5):

Step 1: Select Hand tool from Home menu.

Step 2: Right click on the highlighted part and select DELETE.

I have just tested it in my computer.

Comment: In my case selecting the 'hand tool' didn't work. I had to select the 'Default Mode' in the 'Tools' menu. Only then the Delete option showed up in the context menu.

Comment: The above comment is important — select "Default tool" under "Tools" menu for this answer to work.

Answer (score 0):

This works if the prior two suggestions fail (with Version:  9.7.0.29455)

From Home: click Select > click Select Annotation > then highlight the fields you want to un-highlight and then delete (I used the delete button on the computer).

https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-unhighlight-a-text-in-Foxit-PDF-reader